# CakePHP 3 Migration for Postgres was get PDO Error There is no active transaction for seed data

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, cakephp, pdo

I'm trying to create seed data from CakePHP 3 migration file, with Postgres as database driver. But i have got error message under console after run:

```
bin/cake migrations migrate
```

[image]

Here are my code:

```
<?php
use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Utility\Security;

class CreateSeedUsers extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Migrate Up.
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $modelName = 'Users';

        $data = [
            [
                'username' => 'admin', 
            'email' => 'admin@demo.com', 
                'password' => Security::hash('123', 'sha1', true)
            ], 
            [
                'username' => 'seller', 
            'email' => 'seller@demo.com', 
                'password' => Security::hash('123', 'sha1', true)
            ], 
            [
                'username' => 'member', 
                'email' => 'member@demo.com', 
                'password' => Security::hash('123', 'sha1', true)
            ]
        ];

        $table = TableRegistry::get($modelName);
        $entities = $table->newEntities($data);
        debug($entities);
        // In a controller.
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            // Save entity
            $table->save($entity);
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Migrate Down.
     */
    public function down()
    {
        if ($this->query("TRUNCATE users")) {
            echo " > Table has been initialized\n\n";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo " > Warning, table failed to initialized!!!\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

If i use mysql as database driver, its working good.

Someone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Open a ticket in the issue tracker, this is a bug https://github.com/cakephp/migrations

Comment: Please have a look at postgresql logs, there should be some error message which could explain what is wrong.

Comment: Ok Jose Lorenzo. I was created new ticket at https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/83. Thanks.